# Symlink becomes copy after saving it

Tags: filesystem, pdf, symbolic-link

I have the issue that if I make a symlink to a PDF, then open the symlink and make any sort of change to it, if I save the symlink becomes a hard copy of the changes rather the changes happening to the target PDF. For instance, here is a symlink to a shipping label PDF,

[image]

and here it is as a hard copy after opening the target PDF through the symlink and saving a change I made to the target PDF,

[image]

What must I do so the symlink stays a symlink? I should add, I must make the symlink (and any changes to the symlink itself, but not the file it targets) using command lines, in case that alters the solution.

Comment: What kind of changes are you making exactly to the symlink? And with what application? I'm trying to reproduce the behaviour you describe but I am not sure what exactly you did.

Comment: @ByteCommander Generally, my symlink targets are PDFs, and the changes I make are highlighting text using FoxitReader. I can add a "guide" of what I did with images to the OP if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application is probably re-creating the file as a regular file (e.g. imagine a delete followed by file creation).

You can track down this behaviour by using `strace`.

Comment: More likely a "safe write" by saving the changes in a temporary file and then replacing the original with that. Are there any options regarding that in Foxit's settings maybe?

Comment: @ByteCommander Foxit doesn't seem to have any relevant settings. That said, I did a test, and Foxit handles symlinks in Windows without turning them into hard copies. Right now I'm trying to install Master PDF Editor to see if it handles the symlinks but that has its own problems since I need to update QT.

Comment: So it was a problem with the Foxit reader application. Using PDF Studio, for instance, works just fine with the symlink. Thanks.